# Is it possible to assign the value we return with "return" in the function to a value without calling the function itself?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def define():
    a = input("Language:")
    b = input("Version:")

    return a,b

def print_language():
    f = define()
    print(f[0],f[1])

define()
print_language()


Language:Python
Version:3.8
Language:Python
Version:3.8
Python 3.8
```

The output of this is that it calls the function twice like this. I know the solution to this, only to call the 2nd function, but my question is:

Is it possible to assign the values we get from the first function with "return" to a variable, without calling the first function itself, and then, for example, when we send a value into the first function, can we call it and use it without repeating it a second time?

Comment: Try passing it in to `print_language()`, e.g. `def print_language(f):` then you can call `print_language(define())`

Comment: yes, just save the language and the version as global variables

Comment: @Sadap, I personally wouldn't recommend global variables, just pass the results in. Global variables are generally frowned upon, as a sign of a not well thought out program.

Comment: @AChampion, 
  did not work. the same problem continues

Comment: def define():
    a = input("Language:")
    b = input("Version:")
   
def print_language(f):
    print(f[0],f[1])

define()
print_language(define())

Comment: You still have to `return a, b` from `define()`.

Comment: def define():
    a = input("Language:")
    b = input("Version:")
    return a,b
   
def print_language(f):
    print(f[0],f[1])

define()
print_language(define())

Comment: sorry i forgot. but the problem still persists

Comment: @AChampion ,I want to call both functions, but I don't want the first function to repeat itself

Comment: You are calling both functions. `print_language(define())` cals `define()` and passes the results to `print_language()`. You don't call `define()` before `print_language(define())`.

Comment: AChampion, Thank you for your answer, but think of a program consisting of many functions, each of them is sending variables to each other with return, and when you run the last one, the program runs. You said you are calling both functions, but I still can't call them in separate places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the results of `define()` to `print_language()`, e.g.:

```
def print_language(f):
    print(f[0],f[1])

result = define()
print_language(result)
```

Or this can be collapsed to:

```
print_language(define())
```